# Two pane file manager for Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, finder

I recently moved from Linux to Mac, and am missing a two pane file manager.
I was thinking about along the lines of midnight commander, krusader (Linux) or total commander (Windows).

I installed midnight commander and am using it, but a GUI file manager would sometimes be handy.

Any suggestions for Open Source alternatives?

Comment: Let's consolidate this with the other two-pane browser tool. If there are substantial differences in the problem you face, we can edit this so it's clear you are looking for something different than the linked question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout XTrafinder - google for it and download it from the source of your choice...

It can be found [here](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/).

From the website:

> XtraFinder add Tabs and features to Mac Finder.
>
> • Tabs.
>
> • Dual Panel & Dual Window.
>
> • Arrange folders on top.
>
> • Cut & Paste.
>
> • Global hotkeys.
>
> • "Copy Path", "Show Hidden Items", "Hide Desktop", "Refresh", "New
>   File", "Copy to", "Move to", "New Terminal Here", "Make Symbolic
>   Link", "Contents", "Select...", … .
>
> • Light text on dark background.
>
> • Colorful icons in Sidebar.

The nice thing really is that it extends finders usability.

Comment: Can you explain why it meets the asker's requirements.

Comment: @tomTom I found it and I am using it- but it is not actually a two pane file manager - it opens a second instance of finder. But I will try it out.

Comment: It is actually really nice and I am still using it - like it.

Answer (score 1):

[Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com) is nice, has support for FTP + SFTP + Amazon S3 + WEBDav. A bit pricey, but I got it on sale and there were a few discounts again after that so maybe worth a wait.

[Screenshot of Forklift http://shrani.si/f/F/wu/3VAuwxPt/screen-shot-2013-06-27-a.png](http://shrani.si/f/F/wu/3VAuwxPt/screen-shot-2013-06-27-a.png)

You have mentioned Krusader (and wish to use open source software), it can be run on Mac via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). After installing MacPorts use:

```
sudo port install krusader
```

I doubt it will look good, but It should work. It supported Aqua look years ago, so no X11 was needed, but I have no idea how it stands now.

Comment: Yes - forklift looks nice, but I was looking for something Open Source (Linux heritage...). I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

I like [mucommander](http://www.mucommander.com/).  It is cross-platform, to boot, very much like `mc`, but with a GUI instead of a 'TUI', and allows you to connect to, say, SFTP shares and such.

[image]

Comment: I found mucommander before, but I simply don't like java. At least under Linux, they looked funny and usually were slow. But I might give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/), which supports dual-mode as well as some other great features. (I most like the tab support.)

[image]

Comment: Looks very similar to Xtrafinder - any substantial difference justifying the 18$ pricetag?

Comment: I don't know -- I only learned about Xtrafinder when I posted my response here so haven't tried it.